# Terraform Azure data factory creation

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to deploy Azure data factory along with customer managed key and identity but after terraform apply customer managed key is not showing in the data factory.
When I try to add the customer managed key manually in data factory it is giving below error.
Operation failed. Managed identity used in CMK not found.

```
    data "azurerm_client_config" "main" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
    name = "rgsupports01"
    location = "East US 2"
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "main" {
    depends_on = [azurerm_resource_group.main]
    name = "supports01-mid"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
    location = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "main" {
  name                        = "supportskv01"
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.main.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false

  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.main.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.main.object_id

    key_permissions = [
      "Get",
      "Unwrapkey",
      "Wrapkey",
      "Create",
      "Delete",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "Get",
    ]

    storage_permissions = [
      "Get",
    ]
  }
}

    resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "main" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.main.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.main.tenant_id
  object_id    = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.main.client_id

  key_permissions = [
    "Get","List","Unwrapkey","Wrapkey"
  ]

  secret_permissions = [
    "Get","List",
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "main" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.main]
  name         = "supportrsakeys01"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.main.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 2048

  key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "sign",
    "unwrapKey",
    "verify",
    "wrapKey",
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "adf" {
    #depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault_key.main]
    name       = "supportdfs01"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
    location = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
    public_network_enabled = false
    customer_managed_key_id = resource.azurerm_key_vault_key.main.id
    identity {
        type = "UserAssigned"
        identity_ids = [resource.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.main.id]
    }

}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "new" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_data_factory.adf]
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.main.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.main.tenant_id
  object_id    = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.main.principal_id

  key_permissions = [
    "Get","List","Unwrapkey","Wrapkey"
  ]

  secret_permissions = [
    "Get","List",
  ]
}
```

Comment: how about you show us your terraform code?!

Comment: update your question and put your code there

Answer (score 0):

Do not specific `access_policy` within the Key Vault resource, only use `azurerm_key_vault_access_policy` resources. The way you have specified it, will bring conflicts and probably mess up access policies. See [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_access_policy).

Comment: I removed access_policy from key vault and deployed the data factory. Customer managed key is empty. Nothing attached. Tried attaching key manually. Still same error :(

Comment: is the key actually present in key vault and did you check in the portal that the access policy is set correctly?

Comment: Yes, I'm generating the key along with the data factory with the above script. I see managed identity, service principle, client id and my user in access policy.

Comment: Yeah I mean if you can see the key in key vault after terraform apply?

Comment: why do you have this `depends_on = [azurerm_data_factory.adf]`? this would grant access to the key only after adf has been deployed